# Track android app battery consumption?

Tags: android, android-sensors, battery, batterylevel

I'm making an app that collects sensor values and sends them to a server. The main issue is battery draining. I looked for apps and software to have an idea of the energy consumption (per hour for example) because I've used two approaches to achieve what I want and I want to be able to justify my choice (to pick one approach over the other) based on a real experiment or a mathematical formula.

Comment: Which approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a physical device, you can go under **Settings -> Apps** (depends on device), and then look for "Battery". Look under it and you will see "x% used since last fully charged". I have this feature on my Samsung tab, Galaxy Note 4, and Google Pixel Smartphone. You can even click on it and it will show more detail, like "Computed power usage".